# How to assign my home button function to a custom launcher?

Tags: apex-launcher-pro

I installed [Apex Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher) on my S3. It takes some configuring before it is useful, so I didn't assign it to the default action of my home key. I then did accidently set the default action to use the standard launcher.

I can't find any way to now set the Apex shell/launcher/what ever it is to be the default when you press home.

Any ideas how to change my home button function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also run Apex Launcher from the app drawer of your default "stock" launcher. Navigate to Apex settings > ADVANCED > SET DEFAULT LAUNCHER which will do the same thing - clear the default action and display the popup menu allowing you to choose from the launcher apps currently installed on your device.

Comment: Thank you :) I'm sure the above solution from Conn would work too, but embarassingly I could not remember what the other Launcher was called and thus couldn't find it in the list :/

Comment: The default Samsung launcher is called TwLauncher (TouchWiz).

Answer (score 4):

Go to Settings > Apps > Click on the "All" tab then find your current launcher (the one that is default now) in the list. In the App Info page you should have the option to "clear defaults". Click this and the next time you hit the home button you will have the option to select a different launcher.